# Vector force application problem

Tags: problem-solving, vectors

I'm having trouble starting off this question. Any help would be appreciated!

"Lisa is trying to hold on to her toy car.

Her sister Ruby is pulling with a force of 8 N on a bearing of 023° and her brother Mark with a force of 5 N on a bearing of 155°.

What force does Lisa need to exert to keep the toy in equilibrium?"

Answer (score 0):

The forces need to sum up to zero to prevent they toy from moving. The forces exerted by Ruby respectively Mark are $$
  F_R = 8\begin{pmatrix}\cos 23^\circ \\ \sin 23^\circ\end{pmatrix},\,
  F_M = 5\begin{pmatrix}\cos 155^\circ \\ \sin 155^\circ\end{pmatrix}.
$$
so Lisa will have to apply the force $$
  F_L = -F_R - F_M \text{,}
$$
because then $$
  F_L + F_R + F_M = 0 \text{.}
$$

Comment: This was really helpful! However wouldn't it be Fr+Fm=Fl because normally the resulting vector (Vr)--in this case Lisa-- would equal the sum of the other two vectors? In other words, if you combine Mark ands Ruby's force, Lisa's force would have to be the same?

Comment: also, wouldn't it be 67º for Fr and 65º for Fm because we're trying to use theta and the displacement(the amount of newtons) when finding the x and y components of Ruby and Mark?

Comment: @Emm The forces have to sum up to zero, hence the minus. Regarding your second comment - I don't understand what you're trying to say there... What's the "theta and the displacement"?

Comment: Sorry if my second comment wasn't clear. It says a bearing of 23º for Ruby, so wouldn't it be 90º-23º=67º instead of 23º when plugging it into the [8cos(67), 8sin(67)] to find the x and y components (which I later sub into Fr in the equation above)?

Comment: @Emm Why? That'd make "0^\circ" point into the $y$-direction instead of the $x$-direction, but what's the point?